# Decide convergence of the series .

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have problem with these two:

a) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln{\ln{n}})^{\ln{n}}}$

b) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln{n} \cdot \ln{\ln{n}}}$

My try: a) I come to $S_n=(n^{\ln{\ln{\ln{n}}}})^{-1}$ but I don't know what next.

b) using condenstaion test I get $S_n=(n \cdot \ln{2} \cdot \ln{(n\cdot\ln2)})^{-1}$

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy condensation test? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). Also: What have you tried, where are you stuck, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) rewrite the denominator as $n^{\ln(\ln(\ln n))}$, and then compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

b) try using the Integral Test:

Evaluate $\int_3^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln x\ln(\ln x)} dx $ by letting $u=\ln(\ln x)$ and $du=\frac{1}{x\ln x} dx$

Comment: For (b) shouldn't it be with $\int_0^x \frac{du}{u \ln u \ln \ln u} = \ln\ln\ln x$?

Comment: @ClementC. I will try to edit my answer to make it clearer what I meant.